# Empty response with Apollo graphql and Nginx

Tags: nginx, graphql, reverse-proxy, apollo-server

Our application exposes a graphql API through Apollo, Express and Nest.js. In the prod/staging environments, the application is deployed behind a Nginx ingress (kubernetes). The API works fine in the production environment and with `kubectl port-forward`. But, when we try to use the API behind Nginx, the HTTP response hangs (TCP timeout) when the response payload is higher then approximately 1 KB. Some conclusions we have:

- The application is working properly (we see by the logs that it is returning the correct response);
- We tried to increase Nginx proxy-buffer-size, without success;
- We tried to return the same payload on an usual REST endpoint (no graphql, just Nest.js controller) and it worked!

So, it seems to be a problem related to the integration between Nginx as a proxy and Apollo server. Does anybody have any thoughts on that?

Here is an example of a curl request which causes the problem:

```
 $ curl -v --location --request POST 'https://my-company.com/graphql' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"query":"query {\n  myQueryHere \n}","variables":{}}'
  Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
  *   Trying <my-ip-here>...
  * TCP_NODELAY set
  * Connected to my-company (my-ip-here) port 443 (#0)
  * ALPN, offering h2
  * ALPN, offering http/1.1
  * successfully set certificate verify locations:
  *   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
  * (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  * (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
  * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
  * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
  * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
  * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
  * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
  * ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
  * Server certificate:
  *  subject: CN=*.mycompany.com
  *  start date: Dec  4 00:00:00 2019 GMT
  *  expire date: Jan  4 12:00:00 2021 GMT
  *  subjectAltName: host "my-company" matched cert's "*.my-company"
  *  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
  *  SSL certificate verify ok.
  > POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
  > Host: my-company
  > User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
  > Accept: */*
  > Content-Type: application/json
  > Content-Length: 159
  > 
  * upload completely sent off: 159 out of 159 bytes
  * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
  * Empty reply from server
  * Connection #0 to host my-company left intact
  curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: Have you checked your nginx logs for potential errors?

Comment: Yes! Nothing wrong in the logs, only the access entries.

Comment: Can you share your ingress.yaml file?